# image dispaly fail SOOMETIMES with QT&&VS in C++

Tags: c++, qt

```
connect(myThread2, SIGNAL(label_display1()), this, SLOT(display_camera1()));
void MainWindow::display_camera1()
{
            QImage* QmyImage = new QImage();
        //判断是黑白、彩色图像
        if (myImage1->channels()>1)
        {
            //将myImage1中的数据传给QImage
            *QmyImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(myImage1->data), myImage1->cols, myImage1->rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        }
        else
        {
            *QmyImage = QImage((const unsigned char*)(myImage1->data), myImage1->cols, myImage1->rows, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        }

        *QmyImage = (*QmyImage).scaled(ui->imageView1->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
        //显示图像
        ui->imageView1->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*QmyImage));
        delete QmyImage;
        QmyImage = NULL;
}
```

There are 2 display() signals. One image is displayed well but the other is not. When the .exe runs for a time(maybe 4 hours),the screen where should show the image begins to be grey.But the threads run well. The display is the only problem.
Do you have some experience like this or some steps to deal with it?Thank you.

Comment: You can allocate the `QImage` on the stack. You will save yourself a lot of code and potential problems. Moreover, if you start having problems after a longer program running, this may indicate that you are leaking some memory (which is quite likely given your bad style of allocating unnecessary stuff on the heap instead of stack) and you computer RAM got exhausted. Check how much memory you program occupies after longer run, is it still the same amount as when it is started? If it is much bigger, then you have a leak.

Comment: And another piece of advice: stop using the old style of connections, use the new style. You will save yourself also a lots of troubels with it. See https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: fine thank you! i will check the memory and try the new connections.